# Attenuation only at transmit without affecting receiver

Tags: amplifier, rf, attenuator, 3g, 4g

My office in a basement and I have bought an amplifier in AliExpress to be able to make calls from the basement.
The local cellular company says my amplifier is blocking close by cells (oops). Is there a way to attenuate the transmission power without hurting the receiver signal (one way attenuator?). I cannot find a power tune button in the product so it seems it cannot be changed.

This is the image and link for the amplifier:

[image]

Comment: It's likely that the device isn't licenced for use, check local laws also.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone doesn't work in the basement. Why? Either the closest cellular tower cannot generate strong enough field into your office or your phone has too weak transmitter to reach the tower through the concrete. I guess your repeater is in somewhere upper in the building. It can well work.

Essentially your transmitter uses a part of the same frequency range that the local cellular operator has rented from the state and paid a long penny for it. I'm afraid they are not going to let you to use it as you like.

An antenna could in theory be made lossy for strong signals - a diode limiter in the cable, but making it work in GHz frequencies is far from trivial. If a casual tinkerer succeeds to make one work it's a kind of miracle.

A passive outdoor antenna would in theory be the legal solution, but most phones do not have a place to connect one. A cradle which connects the internal phone antenna to an external antenna may work in theory if it's made for a certain phone, but I wouldn't buy one before seeing it works in practice in my place.

Check from the local cellphone company what they will accept. Do not pay anything before you see it works! The web is full of junk cellphone connection booster ads and DIY pranks. This is a typical one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oHVoXf7jF4